# Flow Challenge: Trying to loop a single records fields values to do different actions

Tags: visual-workflow, loop

I'm working on a project to send emails to customers based on whether or not a user checks a certain box(es); I have 4 boxes in total they could check.

**Problem**: Have user be able to trigger flow when any of the checkboxes are selected. If they select 1 they send a single email; If they select all, it sends all 4 emails.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to chain together the decisions so that you can check all four conditions. That part will look like this:

[image: Chain Decision Flow]

Comment: Thanks for that response! I'll check that out and see what the results are.

Comment: Great stuff, really appreciate it.